# Align Table Columns Underneath Grouped Bar Chart D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to align the columns of my table underneath a Group Bar Chart. I was working off a previous example I found but it's not quite there and I can't figure out why. It seems to work great when there are fewer values on the x-axis.

I've set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf97m3r/2/) to show my issue. I'm trying to use the label width and the bandwidth of the axis to set my table column widths. It's close, but not completely accurate. Not sure what I'm missing.

Here is where I add the table:

```
var tableData = [];
tableData = totalBaseSalesTableData;
var newTableSelector = "#table6";
var newTableColWidth = x0.bandwidth();
var newTableHeaderColWidth = 100;
// var barPadding = x1.range()[1] - x1.range()[0] - x1.bandwidth();

// Bind data to placeholder rows
var tr = d3.select(newTableSelector).selectAll("tr")
  .data(tableData)
  .enter().append("tr");

// Populate table
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("td")
  .style("color", function(d) {
    let temp;
    temp = d;
    if (isNaN(temp)) {
      return z(temp)
    } else {
      return "black";
    }
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    let temp;
    temp = d;
    if (isNaN(temp)) {
      return temp;
    } else {
      return temp + "%"
    }
  });

// Style header column
var tdHeader = tr.select("td")
  .attr("width", newTableHeaderColWidth + (labelWidth / 2))
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-size", "12px")
  .style("text-align", "center");

// Style data cells
var tdData = tr.selectAll("td:not(:first-child)")
  .attr("width", newTableColWidth + labelWidth)
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("font-size", "12px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set your `chart` and `table` same width, i.e.

```
d3.select(newTableSelector).attr("width",  width + margin.left + margin.right);
```

Something you should pay attention:

1.set min-width for both otherwise table content will be overlap
2.if resize the widow, chart pos will be change because you set transform attr
for chart like `.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")` , but table not.

Comment: Hey Winky, yeah the resize issue is definitely present since I don't redraw on a window resize. As for setting the chart and table to the same width, it seems like they are already the same width. Explicitly setting it in the fiddle doesn't seem to make a difference.